# Generated DbContext only has empty constructor

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I'm just getting started with VS2012 and EF5 and am writing an app that needs to be able to connect to one of a variety of databases with identical schema. MSDN shows a DbContext constructor that takes a connection string as a parameter, but for some reason my generated context only includes and empty constructor.

If I manually add the constructor to the generated class then it works fine, but I don't want to have to do this every time after updating my model.

Anyone ever run into this before?

Comment: You can add a partial class for the derived DbContext class where you would add the ctor with the parameter. This way you would not have to re-add the ctor each time the code is generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a partial class for the derived DbContext class where you would add the ctor with the parameter. This way you would not have to re-add the ctor each time the code is re-generated.